# Can't use mongoose's response object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am stuck with something very very silly and it's driving me nuts.

Problem:

```
function getPostsCount(callback) {
        userPostsModel.findOne({'profileID':req.session.facebookProfileId}, function(err, usersPostCountDB) {
            if(usersPostCountDB) {
                console.log('usersPostCountDB found and the userPost var passed with it is: ' + usersPostCountDB.postsCount);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(usersPostCountDB));
                callback(null, usersPostCountDB.postsCount);
            } else {
                console.log('There was an error getting the postsCount');
                callback(true, null);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the weird part, I am getting the below:

```
usersPostCountDB found and the userPost var passed with it is: undefined
```

Furthermore, I have looked at the next line's response and I am getting the object and it's postsCount variable properly. It looks like so:

[image]

My schema looks like the below:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
   profileID:       String,
   fullname:        String,
   profilePic:      String,
   email:           String,
   birthday:        String,
   location:        String,
   about:           String,
   likes:           [],
   interests:       [],
   postsCount:      String,
   posts:           [],
   postsAgreed:     [],
   postsDisagreed:  [],
   dateCreated:     String
});
mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'users');
```

Any ideas all? I really need the help at this point.

Thanks,
Shayan

Comment: Sounds like you don't have `postsCount` declared in your schema.

Comment: @robertklep - I have edited the question to have the Schema. As you can now see, it's there. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's there alright. You don't have any Mongoose middleware/hooks that may be causing the problem?

Comment: @robertklep - not in this case. It seems like I am doing everything correct and yet it's still not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a breakpoint (don't know why I didn't think of that right-away) and found that the usersPostCountDB object has a _doc object which had all the variables.

So to get it, I just used:

```
usersPostCountDB._doc.postsCount
```

Instead of:

```
usersPostCountDB.postsCount
```